# How to use 2 for loop in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning ruby on rails and i am trying to iterate my data from 2 loops. But didn't know how it can be possible.

Here is my array in controller:

```
@players = [1, 2, 3]

        for(@i; @i < @players; @i++)
            for(@j = @i+1; @j < @players; @j++)
                puts @i "with" @j
            end
        end
```

I want `[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]` as a result

Comment: BTW, in Ruby the syntax is `for i in @players`. But as the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop) say: _"The `for` loop is rarely used in modern ruby programs."_

Comment: I don't understand `@i < @players`: @players is an array, and `@i` is not initialized, so at least initially `nil`. What do you expect the comparision to do? Also, `++` is not a valid Ruby operator. The whole piece of code does not look to me like Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all combinations of size 2 (1st and 2nd, 1st and 3rd, 2nd and 3rd) can use [`Array#combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#combination-method). With a block, it will yield each pair:

```
@players = [1, 2, 3]

@players.combination(2) do |i, j|
  puts "#{i} with #{j}"
end
```

Output:

```
1 with 2
1 with 3
2 with 3
```

Without a block, `combination` returns an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html):

```
@players.combination(2)
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>
```

To get an array of combinations, call its [`to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#to_a-method) method:

```
@players.combination(2).to_a
#=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: what does that combination(2) means?

Comment: and i used that but didn't get output as i want. it gives [1,2,3]

Comment: @ShrutiGupta `combination(2)` yields all [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of size 2.

Answer (score 0):

You use `each` to loop

You should read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_overview.htm#

```
@players.each do |player|
   p player
end
```

Comment: yaaa but this will print only single items. But i want [1,2], [1,3],[2,3] as a result

Comment: The first time, you don't show result you want ? so, i will update again.

Comment: hmm i missed that part @lihnNguyen thanks